# Numpy: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I have a numpy array `R` of dimensions `150x3` and another numpy array `D` for dimensions`150x4`.

I am trying to `np.dot(R.T, D)` but I get

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,150) (150,4)

But when I do `np.dot(D.T, R)`, I don't get any error.

What is wrong in `np.dot(R.T, D)`?

```
R = [[  9.61020742e-02   3.46156874e-01   5.57741052e-01]
 [  7.89559849e-03   1.94729924e-01   7.97374478e-01]
 [  9.86036469e-03   3.58806741e-01   6.31332895e-01]
 [  2.48034126e-03   8.04021220e-01   1.93498439e-01]
 [  8.83193916e-02   5.48842033e-01   3.62838576e-01]
 [  3.71353736e-01   1.17560018e-01   5.11086246e-01]
 [  1.06980365e-02   4.27750286e-01   5.61551678e-01]
 [  3.86811475e-02   6.15241737e-01   3.46077116e-01]
 [  8.72297668e-04   6.71562777e-01   3.27564925e-01]
 [  6.89735774e-03   8.56750517e-01   1.36352125e-01]
 [  3.56313831e-01   2.78079828e-01   3.65606341e-01]
 [  7.57943813e-03   9.18418851e-01   7.40017112e-02]
 [  5.41821292e-03   7.30246525e-01   2.64335263e-01]
 [  1.47647182e-03   6.71706805e-01   3.26816723e-01]
 [  8.04498616e-01   3.75237147e-03   1.91749012e-01]
 [  8.97990546e-01   5.24969629e-03   9.67597575e-02]
 [  2.19970730e-01   4.20443727e-03   7.75824833e-01]
 [  6.09849253e-02   7.81150046e-02   8.60900070e-01]
 [  5.82902465e-01   7.96470608e-02   3.37450474e-01]
 [  1.90567056e-01   3.44574089e-01   4.64858855e-01]
 [  1.18054009e-01   5.35847701e-01   3.46098290e-01]
 [  8.64050519e-02   6.25795101e-02   8.51015438e-01]
 [  3.78483444e-02   2.02516101e-01   7.59635554e-01]
 [  8.59779741e-03   1.45064881e-02   9.76895714e-01]
 [  9.99346444e-04   9.94183378e-01   4.81727604e-03]
 [  9.40391340e-03   4.85716808e-01   5.04879279e-01]
 [  2.13243738e-02   8.65263690e-02   8.92149257e-01]
 [  1.15701417e-01   4.32636874e-01   4.51661709e-01]
 [  8.86018157e-02   1.84982960e-01   7.26415224e-01]
 [  3.01781162e-03   9.01584406e-01   9.53977822e-02]
 [  4.56990100e-03   7.91352466e-01   2.04077633e-01]
 [  3.45927029e-02   4.87892600e-03   9.60528371e-01]
 [  1.60632883e-01   8.27044274e-01   1.23228432e-02]
 [  8.35100215e-01   9.16902815e-02   7.32095037e-02]
 [  1.07230994e-02   4.73656742e-01   5.15620159e-01]
 [  1.87299922e-02   4.60373499e-02   9.35232658e-01]
 [  2.00924000e-01   2.51558825e-02   7.73920117e-01]
 [  2.70681415e-02   9.19211663e-01   5.37201953e-02]
 [  1.59735470e-03   5.41196014e-01   4.57206631e-01]
 [  5.95274793e-02   4.87221419e-01   4.53251102e-01]
 [  4.30642592e-02   5.31354413e-02   9.03800300e-01]
 [  4.82644394e-05   6.88366845e-03   9.93068067e-01]
 [  2.68874993e-03   7.18010358e-01   2.79300892e-01]
 [  6.64131338e-03   3.02540302e-03   9.90333284e-01]
 [  7.16077254e-02   7.62597372e-01   1.65794903e-01]
 [  3.26066793e-03   5.55729613e-02   9.41166371e-01]
 [  8.29860613e-02   8.51236805e-01   6.57771335e-02]
 [  4.92325113e-03   7.02327028e-01   2.92749721e-01]
 [  2.68651482e-01   4.07439949e-01   3.23908569e-01]
 [  3.48779651e-02   3.09743232e-01   6.55378803e-01]
 [  4.10371575e-02   3.25115421e-02   9.26451300e-01]
 [  4.23526092e-03   1.57896741e-02   9.79975065e-01]
 [  1.42010306e-02   3.56402209e-02   9.50158749e-01]
 [  1.89270683e-05   1.92636219e-02   9.80717451e-01]
 [  8.41129311e-04   5.24018083e-03   9.93918690e-01]
 [  1.69895846e-04   8.43802871e-01   1.56027233e-01]
 [  3.85831004e-03   3.59151277e-02   9.60226562e-01]
 [  2.66002749e-05   2.11684374e-01   7.88289025e-01]
 [  7.94266474e-03   1.78764870e-01   8.13292465e-01]
 [  2.86578904e-05   2.34398695e-02   9.76531473e-01]
 [  6.82866492e-06   1.83193984e-01   8.16799188e-01]
 [  3.43681400e-04   5.48735560e-03   9.94168963e-01]
 [  2.78629059e-04   2.56309299e-01   7.43412072e-01]
 [  1.12432440e-03   5.03094267e-01   4.95781409e-01]
 [  1.84562605e-04   2.85767672e-03   9.96957761e-01]
 [  8.00369161e-03   6.38415085e-03   9.85612158e-01]
 [  3.04872236e-04   2.93281239e-01   7.06413889e-01]
 [  2.44072328e-04   9.43368816e-01   5.63871119e-02]
 [  1.96883860e-05   9.11261180e-04   9.99069050e-01]
 [  1.98351546e-04   3.20962243e-01   6.78839406e-01]
 [  2.68683180e-04   1.02490410e-02   9.89482276e-01]
 [  6.35566443e-04   6.62457274e-03   9.92739861e-01]
 [  2.52439050e-04   6.96820959e-02   9.30065465e-01]
 [  2.43286411e-04   9.69657837e-01   3.00988762e-02]
 [  3.35900677e-03   3.47740518e-02   9.61866941e-01]
 [  4.11624011e-03   7.18683241e-03   9.88696927e-01]
 [  5.05652417e-03   4.91264721e-02   9.45817004e-01]
 [  1.38735573e-03   3.77829350e-03   9.94834351e-01]
 [  4.77430724e-04   3.62754653e-02   9.63247104e-01]
 [  5.06295723e-04   6.35474249e-02   9.35946279e-01]
 [  9.80128411e-05   1.72085050e-01   8.27816937e-01]
 [  1.46161671e-04   3.57717082e-01   6.42136756e-01]
 [  4.33049391e-04   5.20091202e-02   9.47557830e-01]
 [  1.78321609e-04   4.12044951e-01   5.87776727e-01]
 [  1.46347921e-04   5.31652774e-01   4.68200878e-01]
 [  2.46735826e-03   3.67683627e-02   9.60764279e-01]
 [  6.61311324e-03   1.54005833e-02   9.77986303e-01]
 [  1.77071930e-04   1.46768447e-02   9.85146083e-01]
 [  6.83094720e-04   3.13743642e-01   6.85573264e-01]
 [  5.09993051e-05   4.09115493e-02   9.59037451e-01]
 [  2.85804634e-05   9.48028881e-01   5.19425385e-02]
 [  1.87256703e-03   3.68745243e-01   6.29382190e-01]
 [  3.18003668e-04   8.67846435e-02   9.12897353e-01]
 [  2.15156635e-05   9.92444712e-02   9.00734013e-01]
 [  2.01886324e-04   2.67326809e-01   7.32471305e-01]
 [  6.17534155e-04   8.27995308e-01   1.71387158e-01]
 [  6.02903061e-04   3.23796846e-01   6.75600251e-01]
 [  2.29637394e-03   8.97763923e-02   9.07927234e-01]
 [  1.56780115e-05   1.27044886e-03   9.98713873e-01]
 [  3.76740795e-04   1.12972313e-01   8.86650946e-01]
 [  2.87005949e-05   2.22682411e-04   9.99748617e-01]
 [  1.51773249e-05   5.95561038e-03   9.94029212e-01]
 [  6.30006944e-04   1.06470667e-03   9.98305286e-01]
 [  4.17533071e-04   4.37824954e-01   5.61757513e-01]
 [  7.78017325e-05   1.24821334e-03   9.98673985e-01]
 [  6.86924196e-03   5.69614667e-02   9.36169291e-01]
 [  1.79387456e-06   4.14092395e-02   9.58588967e-01]
 [  4.19616727e-03   7.79044623e-01   2.16759210e-01]
 [  2.61103942e-04   1.25771751e-01   8.73967146e-01]
 [  7.08940723e-04   1.96467049e-05   9.99271413e-01]
 [  2.44579204e-04   1.79856898e-04   9.99575564e-01]
 [  6.42095442e-05   1.90401210e-03   9.98031778e-01]
 [  1.51746207e-04   1.13628244e-04   9.99734626e-01]
 [  1.53192339e-06   2.61257119e-04   9.99737211e-01]
 [  2.97672241e-07   5.89714434e-07   9.99999113e-01]
 [  2.31629596e-05   6.05785563e-06   9.99970779e-01]
 [  1.15482703e-03   1.41118116e-01   8.57727057e-01]
 [  1.65303872e-01   1.95290038e-01   6.39406091e-01]
 [  3.87539407e-04   2.76367328e-03   9.96848787e-01]
 [  3.64304533e-05   2.12756841e-01   7.87206729e-01]
 [  1.32951469e-04   2.07806473e-05   9.99846268e-01]
 [  4.71164398e-06   5.41626002e-04   9.99453662e-01]
 [  7.37701536e-03   2.26568147e-01   7.66054837e-01]
 [  5.19394987e-05   5.08165056e-04   9.99439895e-01]
 [  9.41246091e-04   3.90044573e-03   9.95158308e-01]
 [  1.70565028e-02   5.24482561e-01   4.58460936e-01]
 [  5.79928507e-05   4.85233058e-04   9.99456774e-01]
 [  1.71363177e-04   4.43037286e-03   9.95398264e-01]
 [  3.65223499e-05   9.98234443e-04   9.98965243e-01]
 [  1.03256791e-02   7.82752824e-01   2.06921497e-01]
 [  3.39500386e-03   3.19231731e-02   9.64681823e-01]
 [  4.42402046e-01   1.33305750e-01   4.24292203e-01]
 [  1.50282347e-05   1.46067493e-04   9.99838904e-01]
 [  7.75031897e-04   6.09241229e-01   3.89983739e-01]
 [  2.82386491e-06   9.99311738e-01   6.85438538e-04]
 [  4.49243709e-04   7.25519763e-06   9.99543501e-01]
 [  4.52262007e-05   5.28929786e-05   9.99901881e-01]
 [  1.35577576e-03   2.85828013e-01   7.12816211e-01]
 [  1.15450174e-04   2.87523077e-03   9.97009319e-01]
 [  2.33931095e-04   3.96689006e-05   9.99726400e-01]
 [  1.88516051e-05   2.20935448e-06   9.99978939e-01]
 [  1.95262213e-05   5.10008372e-08   9.99980423e-01]
 [  1.51773249e-05   5.95561038e-03   9.94029212e-01]
 [  1.81083155e-04   2.23844268e-04   9.99595073e-01]
 [  2.70194754e-05   1.79050294e-06   9.99971190e-01]
 [  1.07794371e-05   2.41601142e-07   9.99988979e-01]
 [  9.80962323e-06   8.73547012e-05   9.99902836e-01]
 [  1.12317424e-04   2.11402370e-04   9.99676280e-01]
 [  5.84789388e-05   9.18351123e-05   9.99849686e-01]
 [  1.84899708e-04   7.34680565e-02   9.26347044e-01]]
```

and

```
D = [[ 5.1  3.5  1.4  0.2]
 [ 4.9  3.   1.4  0.2]
 [ 4.7  3.2  1.3  0.2]
 [ 4.6  3.1  1.5  0.2]
 [ 5.   3.6  1.4  0.2]
 [ 5.4  3.9  1.7  0.4]
 [ 4.6  3.4  1.4  0.3]
 [ 5.   3.4  1.5  0.2]
 [ 4.4  2.9  1.4  0.2]
 [ 4.9  3.1  1.5  0.1]
 [ 5.4  3.7  1.5  0.2]
 [ 4.8  3.4  1.6  0.2]
 [ 4.8  3.   1.4  0.1]
 [ 4.3  3.   1.1  0.1]
 [ 5.8  4.   1.2  0.2]
 [ 5.7  4.4  1.5  0.4]
 [ 5.4  3.9  1.3  0.4]
 [ 5.1  3.5  1.4  0.3]
 [ 5.7  3.8  1.7  0.3]
 [ 5.1  3.8  1.5  0.3]
 [ 5.4  3.4  1.7  0.2]
 [ 5.1  3.7  1.5  0.4]
 [ 4.6  3.6  1.   0.2]
 [ 5.1  3.3  1.7  0.5]
 [ 4.8  3.4  1.9  0.2]
 [ 5.   3.   1.6  0.2]
 [ 5.   3.4  1.6  0.4]
 [ 5.2  3.5  1.5  0.2]
 [ 5.2  3.4  1.4  0.2]
 [ 4.7  3.2  1.6  0.2]
 [ 4.8  3.1  1.6  0.2]
 [ 5.4  3.4  1.5  0.4]
 [ 5.2  4.1  1.5  0.1]
 [ 5.5  4.2  1.4  0.2]
 [ 4.9  3.1  1.5  0.2]
 [ 5.   3.2  1.2  0.2]
 [ 5.5  3.5  1.3  0.2]
 [ 4.9  3.6  1.4  0.1]
 [ 4.4  3.   1.3  0.2]
 [ 5.1  3.4  1.5  0.2]
 [ 5.   3.5  1.3  0.3]
 [ 4.5  2.3  1.3  0.3]
 [ 4.4  3.2  1.3  0.2]
 [ 5.   3.5  1.6  0.6]
 [ 5.1  3.8  1.9  0.4]
 [ 4.8  3.   1.4  0.3]
 [ 5.1  3.8  1.6  0.2]
 [ 4.6  3.2  1.4  0.2]
 [ 5.3  3.7  1.5  0.2]
 [ 5.   3.3  1.4  0.2]
 [ 7.   3.2  4.7  1.4]
 [ 6.4  3.2  4.5  1.5]
 [ 6.9  3.1  4.9  1.5]
 [ 5.5  2.3  4.   1.3]
 [ 6.5  2.8  4.6  1.5]
 [ 5.7  2.8  4.5  1.3]
 [ 6.3  3.3  4.7  1.6]
 [ 4.9  2.4  3.3  1. ]
 [ 6.6  2.9  4.6  1.3]
 [ 5.2  2.7  3.9  1.4]
 [ 5.   2.   3.5  1. ]
 [ 5.9  3.   4.2  1.5]
 [ 6.   2.2  4.   1. ]
 [ 6.1  2.9  4.7  1.4]
 [ 5.6  2.9  3.6  1.3]
 [ 6.7  3.1  4.4  1.4]
 [ 5.6  3.   4.5  1.5]
 [ 5.8  2.7  4.1  1. ]
 [ 6.2  2.2  4.5  1.5]
 [ 5.6  2.5  3.9  1.1]
 [ 5.9  3.2  4.8  1.8]
 [ 6.1  2.8  4.   1.3]
 [ 6.3  2.5  4.9  1.5]
 [ 6.1  2.8  4.7  1.2]
 [ 6.4  2.9  4.3  1.3]
 [ 6.6  3.   4.4  1.4]
 [ 6.8  2.8  4.8  1.4]
 [ 6.7  3.   5.   1.7]
 [ 6.   2.9  4.5  1.5]
 [ 5.7  2.6  3.5  1. ]
 [ 5.5  2.4  3.8  1.1]
 [ 5.5  2.4  3.7  1. ]
 [ 5.8  2.7  3.9  1.2]
 [ 6.   2.7  5.1  1.6]
 [ 5.4  3.   4.5  1.5]
 [ 6.   3.4  4.5  1.6]
 [ 6.7  3.1  4.7  1.5]
 [ 6.3  2.3  4.4  1.3]
 [ 5.6  3.   4.1  1.3]
 [ 5.5  2.5  4.   1.3]
 [ 5.5  2.6  4.4  1.2]
 [ 6.1  3.   4.6  1.4]
 [ 5.8  2.6  4.   1.2]
 [ 5.   2.3  3.3  1. ]
 [ 5.6  2.7  4.2  1.3]
 [ 5.7  3.   4.2  1.2]
 [ 5.7  2.9  4.2  1.3]
 [ 6.2  2.9  4.3  1.3]
 [ 5.1  2.5  3.   1.1]
 [ 5.7  2.8  4.1  1.3]
 [ 6.3  3.3  6.   2.5]
 [ 5.8  2.7  5.1  1.9]
 [ 7.1  3.   5.9  2.1]
 [ 6.3  2.9  5.6  1.8]
 [ 6.5  3.   5.8  2.2]
 [ 7.6  3.   6.6  2.1]
 [ 4.9  2.5  4.5  1.7]
 [ 7.3  2.9  6.3  1.8]
 [ 6.7  2.5  5.8  1.8]
 [ 7.2  3.6  6.1  2.5]
 [ 6.5  3.2  5.1  2. ]
 [ 6.4  2.7  5.3  1.9]
 [ 6.8  3.   5.5  2.1]
 [ 5.7  2.5  5.   2. ]
 [ 5.8  2.8  5.1  2.4]
 [ 6.4  3.2  5.3  2.3]
 [ 6.5  3.   5.5  1.8]
 [ 7.7  3.8  6.7  2.2]
 [ 7.7  2.6  6.9  2.3]
 [ 6.   2.2  5.   1.5]
 [ 6.9  3.2  5.7  2.3]
 [ 5.6  2.8  4.9  2. ]
 [ 7.7  2.8  6.7  2. ]
 [ 6.3  2.7  4.9  1.8]
 [ 6.7  3.3  5.7  2.1]
 [ 7.2  3.2  6.   1.8]
 [ 6.2  2.8  4.8  1.8]
 [ 6.1  3.   4.9  1.8]
 [ 6.4  2.8  5.6  2.1]
 [ 7.2  3.   5.8  1.6]
 [ 7.4  2.8  6.1  1.9]
 [ 7.9  3.8  6.4  2. ]
 [ 6.4  2.8  5.6  2.2]
 [ 6.3  2.8  5.1  1.5]
 [ 6.1  2.6  5.6  1.4]
 [ 7.7  3.   6.1  2.3]
 [ 6.3  3.4  5.6  2.4]
 [ 6.4  3.1  5.5  1.8]
 [ 6.   3.   4.8  1.8]
 [ 6.9  3.1  5.4  2.1]
 [ 6.7  3.1  5.6  2.4]
 [ 6.9  3.1  5.1  2.3]
 [ 5.8  2.7  5.1  1.9]
 [ 6.8  3.2  5.9  2.3]
 [ 6.7  3.3  5.7  2.5]
 [ 6.7  3.   5.2  2.3]
 [ 6.3  2.5  5.   1.9]
 [ 6.5  3.   5.2  2. ]
 [ 6.2  3.4  5.4  2.3]
 [ 5.9  3.   5.1  1.8]]
```

Comment: Please provide `type(R)` and `type(D)`.

Comment: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Comment: One more please, `R.dtype`, `D.dtype`, The Python and Numpy version

Comment: It shouldn't raise an error. Please include a minimal reproducible example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Python version: 3.3.1
Numpy Version: 1.7.1

Comment: @shx2: I have uploaded my data. Sorry for the last time

Comment: Your example works fine in Python 3.4 / Numpy 1.8.1 and Python 2.7.5 / Numpy 1.8.1

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> r = np.random.random((150, 3))
>>> d = np.random.random((150, 4))
>>> 
>>> np.dot(r.T, d)
array([[ 42.50248324,  36.47470278,  37.01957774,  36.7750468 ],
       [ 38.44103843,  32.94992495,  33.91911815,  35.04781215],
       [ 44.35562949,  40.94601697,  40.07220766,  40.87044229]])
>>> np.dot(r.T, d).shape
(3, 4)
>>> 
>>> np.dot(r.T, d) == np.dot(d.T, r).T
array([[ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
>>> 
>>> np.dot(r, d)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: matrices are not aligned

>>> np.version.version
'1.7.1'
```

Works just the same on numpy 1.8.0b2. The only difference is the specific wording of the ValueError message.